# Codeigniter Pagination with Bootstrap 4

Tags: codeigniter, bootstrap-4, pagination, codeigniter-3

I don't know if I was the only one too stupid to set the pagination of codeigniter correctly with Bootstrap 4. So here's the code so you can save your time

Codeigniter config:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://yoururl.com/';
$config['total_rows'] = 200;
$config['per_page'] = 10;
$config['num_links'] = 2;
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
$config['first_link'] = FALSE;
$config['last_link'] = FALSE;
$config['next_link'] = '&raquo;';
$config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['prev_link'] = '&laquo;';
$config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item active" aria-current="page"> <a class="page-link">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></li>';
$config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page-item">';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
$config['attributes'] = array('class' => 'page-link');

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Outpou in view:

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
</nav>
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: The code above works, just wanted to post it because it took me a long time to assign all classes correctly, so the others save time

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question. It is an example of the OP's code "for example" purposes.